# get the title of the active website in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

i would like to know how to find out what the current document title is of the webpage i have my browser navigate to, is this possible or will i need to open a second web request, and parse the html for a title

Answer (score 5):

Ahha! i found the answer, the property is

```
webBrowser.Document.Title
```